# Node Express isn't Redirecting, but instead returning a string

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I'm new to node and angular, trying to figure out how to redirect on a bad request.  Node is essentially a proxy to a RESTful API.  Currently, weather.error is being populated as `Bad Request. Redirecting to /public/400.html`

Server call:

```js
app.get('/currently', function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        exclude: 'minutely,hourly,daily,flags,alerts'
    };
    forecast.get(request.query.latitude, request.query.longitude, options, function(err, res, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in request. \nLatitude: ' + request.query.latitude + '\nLongitude: ' + request.query.longitude);
            var status = data.split('<title>')[1].split(' ')[0]
            if (status === '404') {
                response.status(400).sendFile(__dirname + '/public/images/404/404-' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1) + '.jpg');
            } else if (status === '400') {
                response.redirect(400, '/public/400.html');
            } else {
                response.status(parseInt(status)).end();
            }
        } else {
            response.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```js
angular.module('myApp.weather', [
    'ui.router'
])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('weather', {
              url: '/weather',
              templateUrl: 'app/weather/weather.tmpl.html',
              controller: 'WeatherController as weather'
          });
  }).controller('WeatherController', function($http, $location) {
      var weather = this;
      weather.latitude = '';
      weather.longitude = '';

      weather.getCurrentWeatherByLatLon = function(latitude, longitude) {
          $http.get('/currently?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude)
              .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  weather.data = data;
              })
              .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {//I don't think this should be necessary if I'm handling it in the sever
                  weather.error = data;
                  if(data.indexOf('Bad Request') >= 0) { 
                      console.log('Bad Request')
                      $location.path('/public/400.html'); //doesn't navigate anywhere
                  }
              })
              ;
      };
```

-------------------------------EDIT-------------------------

I've changed my server call to:

```js
app.get('/currently', function(request, response) {
    var options = {
        exclude: 'minutely,hourly,daily,flags,alerts'
    };
    forecast.get(request.query.latitude, request.query.longitude, options, function(err, res, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error in request. \nLatitude: ' + request.query.latitude + '\nLongitude: ' + request.query.longitude);
            var status = data.split('<title>')[1].split(' ')[0]
            response.status(status).send();
        } else {
            response.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
});
```

and the function in my controller to:

```
weather.getCurrentWeatherByLatLon = function(latitude, longitude) {
    $http.get('/currently?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            weather.data = data; // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            weather.error = status
            if (status == 400) {
                console.log('in 400');
                $location.url('/public/400.html');
            } else if (status == 404) {                              
                console.log('in 404');
                $location.url('/public/404.html');
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you yo use the `url` method of the `locationProvider` service, this permit to pass the control of the flow to a controller managed route: yes **you must implement this route with a controller**.

Try with

```
$location.url('/public/400.html');
```

instead of

```
$location.path('/public/400.html');
```

Another option for serve static content is to use the `window` service as:

Try with

```
$window.location.href ='/public/400.html';
```

instead of

```
$location.path('/public/400.html');
```

Benefit to use this instead of the standard javascript window object ([from the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window)):

> A reference to the browser's window object. While window is globally
>   available in JavaScript, it causes testability problems, because it is
>   a global variable. In angular we always refer to it through the
>   $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for
>   testing.

Hope this help

Comment: I've updated the code to use `$location.url('/public/400.html')` and didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: very strange, i recently fix an issue of this type and usually use it. As example take a look [here](https://github.com/mbiagetti/acme-social-frontend/blob/master/app/js/controllers.js#L64) to check if is the same approach. In my scenario the route is managed by a controller. Hope this help

Comment: Do I need a separate controller to handle the 400?

Comment: if you don't want to control the route with a controller but serve only a static html resource you can use the `$window` service. I update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect ajax calls. A redirect made with `response.redirect(400, '/public/400.html')` is just a HTTP response with a "special" header, and this isn't supported by ajax.

If you wan't to handle problems with the request, return a status or likewise and handle it on the client.

Comment: I've edited the server code to just send a status, and my controller to consume the status number in the event of an error.  How do I have angular handle the redirect?  As suggested by Matteo, `$location.url('/public/400.html')` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Does the code trigger any `console.log`? The `var status = data.split('<title>')[1].split(' ')[0]` does not really make sense to me. You could either use an integer there like 400 and use that for redirect or you could do redirection based on the content of the response.

Comment: `var status = data.split('<title>')[1].split(' ')[0]` was removed.  When I was trying to redirect from the server, it would produce the html in a string and I was just stripping the error code.  In the updated code (below the line), I do get console.log to produce `in 400` as expected.

Comment: Okay, then try to use `location.href = '/public/400.html'`. This skips what could go wrong in angular setup, so you can rule that out. Using location object directly removes the possibility for mocking and testing, but right know I guess its more about finding a solution to the problem.

Comment: `location.href = '/public/400.html'` works, I guess I'll see what could go wrong between the two points.